# How to add 'Report Build Status' setting to YAML?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm using Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1 and can't find how to add the '*Report Build Status*' setting to YAML. I want to create YAML that will be the basis for Pipeline, but I need to enable the '*Report Build Status*' setting.

If I save the Pipeline as JSON, I see the '*Report Build Status*' setting (**reportBuildStatus**). But if I save the Pipeline in YAML, then the '*Report Build Status*' setting is **missing**!

What is the problem? See my picture showing this problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I save the Pipeline in YAML, then the '*Report Build Status*' setting is **missing**!

- *Yes, you will be missing with the Report Build Staus as because you can't use that setting in Yaml pipeline as of now.*

[image]

- *For complete information you can go through this [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/4053#issuecomment-485951634) document.*